# How can I discourage a stray cat from harassing my indoor cat?

Tags: cats, behavior

The past two days at around 5:30am, a stray Tom cat has climbed onto my front porch and come right up to our bedroom window. My male indoor cat freaks, jumping and swatting at the Tom. He runs away when I go outside, but returns the next day. I live in the city and don't think that catching and releasing him would be a viable solution. How can we get rid of this guy so we can get some sleep and my cat can get some peace?

Comment: Why is [catching, neutering and releasing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1699) not an option? Many city shelters have loaner traps you can borrow, specifically for these programs.

Comment: Cover your windows at night, so your cat won't be able to see out the window when you're trying to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

On your front porch spread some citrus fruit extract. Also grounded coffee can be used. Both are poisonous for cats and cats avoid such areas.

But unlike feral cats, pet cats have much less common sense. Be careful that your pet cat does not lick them.